# i can't create column in html for this layout, pls advice me how can i do

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is my code

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="https://s21466.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Logo-FIVB-Liga-nacija-1.jpg" width="500" height="640">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hDUG_ZCg5N8/maxresdefault.jpg" width="320" height="213">
      <img src="https://www.4baht.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/turkey-women-team-preview-volley.jpg" width="320" height="213">
      <img src="https://www.4baht.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/germany-women-team-preview-volle.jpg" width="320" height="213">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="https://cdn8.volleyball.it/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/VNL-Femminile-2019.jpeg" width="320" height="426">
      <img src="https://seekvectorlogo.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/federation-internationale-de-volleyball-fivb-vector-logo.png" width="320" height="213">
```

I want a layout like this:

[image]

I have this:

[image]

[image]

how can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a `Grid` layout: e.g. with `grid-template` you set the position of the available areas, then with `grid-area` you assign a specific area to an element

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 
     "c1 c1 c2 c5"
     "c1 c1 c3 c5"
     "c1 c1 c4 c6"
}

section {
  border: 1px #446 solid;
  margin: 2px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.c1 { grid-area: c1; }
.c2 { grid-area: c2; }
.c3 { grid-area: c3; }
.c4 { grid-area: c4; }
.c5 { grid-area: c5; }
.c6 { grid-area: c6; }
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="c1">1</section>
  <section class="c2">2</section>
  <section class="c3">3</section>
  <section class="c4">4</section>
  <section class="c5">5</section>
  <section class="c6">6</section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: as in your example, by placing each image inside every section (and properly giving them a style)

Comment: like ths? `<section class="c1" img src="https://s21466.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Logo-FIVB-Liga-nacija-1.jpg" width="500" height="640" ></section>`

Answer (score 0):

You are not using columns properly. Use this code

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="https://s21466.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Logo-FIVB-Liga-nacija-1.jpg" width="500" height="640">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hDUG_ZCg5N8/maxresdefault.jpg" width="320" height="213">
                <img src="https://www.4baht.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/turkey-women-team-preview-volley.jpg" width="320" height="213">
                <img src="https://www.4baht.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/germany-women-team-preview-volle.jpg" width="320" height="213">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="https://cdn8.volleyball.it/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/VNL-Femminile-2019.jpeg" width="320" height="426">
                <img src="https://seekvectorlogo.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/federation-internationale-de-volleyball-fivb-vector-logo.png" width="320" height="213">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have linked bootstrap properly in your file.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>